# How many sequences $a_1, a_2, \dots,a _{2015}$ that answer the following conditions exist?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

How many sequences $\{a_1, a_2, \dots,a _{2015}\}$ that answer the following conditions exist:

1. For every $i$: $a_i = 1$ or $a_i = -1$
2. The sum of the series is $7$
3. For every $j$ between $1$ and $2015,$ the sum: $a_1 + a_2 + \dots +a_j >0$.

I need to find the amount of all those possible sequences. 
The solution probably has to do with the Catalan numbers.

Comment: I figured out that there are 1011 +1s and 1004 -1s. I tried to find some sort of bijection between the series and Dyck walks. Also a1 = +1 and a2 = +1.

Comment: I have probably solved that questions myself by finding a bijection between all the series of +1s and -1s in the length of 2014 that sum up to 6 and go at least once under the x axis to all the series of +1s and -1s in the length of 2014 that sum up to -8.